# Step interval of "1" not working for me in Highcharts, why?

Tags: highcharts, label

I want to show every single label in my chart (and there are only five of them). But for reasons I don't understand, my

```
 label: { step: 1 }
```

is getting ignored. [Here is the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/wjq9b/2/).

Thanks for any hints what I've overseen or not understood.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using

```
labels:{ step : 1 }
```

try using [**`tickInterval`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval) on y axis.

```
yAxis: {
         tickInterval:1
       }
```

`labels:{ step : n }` using this will display every n<sup>th</sup> label of the axis.

Try the [**`fiddled`**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gopinaghr/wjq9b/5/) version here.

Comment: Just a small note: apparently, this won't work on any Highcharts version. I had to upgrade from 3.0.10 to 4.1.6.

Answer (score 4):

use [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval)

```
yAxis: {
    ...
    tickInterval: 1,
}
```